# ¿Cómo un dominio comprado en godaddy que apunta a un hosting propio no respete el responsive?

Tags: php, jquery, css, dominio

Tengo un hosting en un servidor propio, compré un dominio en godadddy y al momento de navegar con el dominio desde el móvil, este no respeta el responsive (es como si navegara desde la pc), sin embargo, cuando navego desde el móvil con la dirección ip pública sí corre normal.

¿Alguna recomendación?

Comment: Intenta limpiando el cache del navegador teléfono

Comment: Realiza lo que comenta JCAguilera esto es debido a una cookie que determina cargar modo móvil o modo desktop. Te sugiero revises [ask] para que realices tus preguntas y estas sean bien recibidas en el sitio.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys por la recomendación. Ya limpié el caché del navegador. Incluso si se ingresa por primera vez desde otro móvil también sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Abre tu navegador y prueba lo responsivo de tu sitio por dominio

Comment: cambia de hosting yo ocupo hostiguer y esta muy bien no he tenido ningun problema con responsive design aparte de que es muy barato ;)

Comment: que tiene que ver el cambio de hosting, con el responsive que es un tema de frontend?

Comment: What?, no, no tiene que cambiar de hosting, no tiene nada que ver un hosting con los estilos CSS de tu sitio, más bien checa que todas las rutas de tus archivos enlazados de css estén correctas y si realmente las estás jalando...

Comment: Posiblemente sea porque redirecciono a la ip pública de mi hosting con la opción de enmascaramiento, entonces el sitio de origen queda dentro del <frame></frame> que se crea. Y no lea el  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1> de mi sitio web.